# How to Truncate the fetched Date from the DynamoDB in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, substring, truncate

I was fetching the data from the DynamoDB and in this case the data is Date, so it also comes with the time and all,

the code to get the data,

```
<p>{this.sate.createdDate}</p>
```

Output:

> 2021-02-23T02:19:36.670Z

but I only need the Date should be Like this:

Expected Output:

> 2021-02-23

I tried using the substring method but, I didn't get that,
is there any idea on this, please mention them I will try that,

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the string split() method

```
const date = "2021-02-23T02:19:36.670Z"
const date_in_desired_format = time.split("T")[0]; 

console.log(date_in_desired_format); // 2021-02-23
```

an additional tip: if you want to get the date for today in the same format "ISO format"

use this:

```
cosnt today_date_in_ISO_format = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
console.log(today_date_in_ISO_format);
```